# Imputation methods for time series data (non-stationary)

Tags: python, arima, data-imputation, expectation-maximization

I am looking for an impute method for non-stationary time series (financial indeces).
From https://pypi.org/project/impyute/ (https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/impyute/latest/impyute.pdf) I see that they mention 3 methods:

- Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average
- Expectation Maximization with the Kalman Filter
- Last Observation Carried Forward

Now, at least for the first, the assumption of an ARIMA should be the error being Gaussian white noise, therefore I guess that for my non-stationary case is not the best.

The second I do not know honestly the assumptions behind and don't know how to implement it (in the link above they do not provide example of this methods).
The last seems for me so far the best choice.

Can anybody give me an advice on this please?
In case the second is the best way, may you provide a link with example code?

Comment: Nonstationarity is not a problem for ARIMA as the assumption is for errors, not the original time series. Normality might be a bigger concern as log-returns are typically nonnormal, especially if sampled at high frequencies (daily and higher).

Comment: you are right on ARIMA, my bad. My data are monthly. Do you have any reference/code where ARIMA is used for imputing missing values in python?

Comment: No, I do not...